# How to change Is Multiple Resource Refresh Token to true in Azure AD authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to authenticate my application using azure AD. But at one time I am able to login at one place. When I am trying to login in other place it is not authenticating. I read somewhere that IsMultipleResourceRefreshToken should be true in AuthenticationResult. Can anyone help me how to get IsMultipleResourceRefreshToken to true in Azure AD authentication?

Comment: How are you authenticating to Azure AD? OAuth, WS-Fed, etc.?

Answer (score 3):

The IsMultipleResourceRefreshToken flag describes the nature of the refresh token you received. You cannot change it. However, there should be no scenarios TODAY in which the refresh token returned by Azure AD is not multi resource. I recommend you ensure you are using the absolute latest version of ADAL and that you are actually using a flow that returns a refresh token.
Furthermore: it is unclear if "login to another place" refers to obtaining a token for another resource, or for another tenant. If the latter, please note that tokens are always bound to their tenant and do not enable the issuance of new tokens for a different tenant.

Comment: I am trying to login from other resource. i am getting httpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated is false in other resource. which means it is not authenticating in other resource. do we have any settings in Azure AD which provides IsMultipleResourceRefreshToken flag to true?

Comment: There is no knob for it. As I mentioned, there should be no case today where that flag is not set to true for tokens from Azure AD.The fact that you say "login" is suspicious here. ADAL is not used for login. It is used by a client for obtaining tokens. "IsAuthenticated" is something that is evaluated on the resource side, which you are not even supposed to reach if you weren't able to get a token. Can you review https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios/ and comment on what is the best match for your scenario?